# Reading textfile into dictionary

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary

My code:

```
fd = open('C:\Python27\\alu.txt', 'r')
D = dict(line.split("\n") for line in fd)
```

It shows the following error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ram\Desktop\rest_enz3.py", line 8, in <module>
    D = dict(line.split("\n") for line in fd)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #69 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: How about this? `D = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in fd)`

Comment: Could you give an example file like the one you are trying to read?

Comment: it is a DNA file like ACGTCGCAGCAGACTAGATACGACT

Comment: That's all that's in the file? Only those four letters and nothing else? No line breaks or anything?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936166/unable-to-parse-just-sequences-from-fasta-file). It may help you!

Comment: Human Alu-Sb subfamily consensus sequence.
GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA
TCACGAGGTCAGGAGATCGAGACCATCCTGGCTAACACGGTGAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAA
AAATACAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGTGGTGGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGC
TGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATCGCGCC
ACTGCACTCCAGCCTGGGCGACAGAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAA

Comment: this is data in my file Kevin,Elric

Comment: How would you to expect fill your dict? Put some example in the question.

Comment: I dont understand what you will gain by indexing a `dict`ioanry with line numbers when you can just store each line in a `list`. Can you show an example where this might be useful? There appears to be an overuse of dictionary in the community which works on DNA sequences ...

Answer (score 1):

The only newline you'll ever find in `line` will be the one at the very end, so `line.split("\n")` will return a list of length 1. Perhaps you meant to use a different delimiter. If your file looks like...

```
lorem:ipsum
dolor:sit
```

Then you should do

```
D=dict(line.strip().split(":") for line in fd)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin above points out, line.split("\n") is a bit odd, but maybe the file is just a list of dictionary keys?

Regardless, the error you get implies that the line.split("\n") returns just a single element (in other words, the line is missing the trailing newline). For example:

```
"Key1\n".split("\n") returns ["Key1", ""]
```

while

```
"Key1".split("\n") returns ["Key1"]


dict([["key1", ""],["key2", ""]])
```

is fine, while

```
dict([["key1, ""],["key2"]])
```

returns the error you quote

It may be as simple as editing the file in question and adding a new line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

**File example: alu.txt**

```
GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA
TCACGAGGTCAGGAGATCGAGACCATCCTGGCTAACACGGTGAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAA
AAATACAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGTGGTGGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGC
TGAGGCAGGAGAATGGCGTGAACCCGGGAGGCGGAGCTTGCAGTGAGCCGAGATCGCGCC
```

**Reading file**

```
with open('C:\\Python27\\alu.txt', 'r') as fp:
    dna = {'Key %i' % i: j.strip() for i, j in enumerate(fp.readlines())}

for key, value in dna.iteritems():
    print key, ':', value

Key 1 : GGCCGGGCGCGGTGGCTCACGCCTGTAATCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCGAGGCGGGCGGA
Key 2 : TCACGAGGTCAGGAGATCGAGACCATCCTGGCTAACACGGTGAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAA
Key 3 : AAATACAAAAATTAGCCGGGCGTGGTGGCGGGCGCCTGTAGTCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGGC
```

If you're using Python 3 change the iteration flow to this way

```
for key, value in dna.items():
    print(key, ':', value)
```

Comment: it shows error     for key,value in dna.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Ok, I had not understood you're using Python 3